# Arithmetic mean sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Let $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ng(k)=A $$

Then for what functions $f(x)$ does $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)g(k)}{\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)}=A$$

Comment: If you want an entire characterization of such functions, I'd be surprised if something exists independent of $g$. Off the top of my head it seems like $f(k)=c\cdot k$ for any nonzero constant $c$ works. But in general if $g(k)=0$ for instance, I don't see a nice classification coming about.

Comment: Sorry I meant $f(k)=c$, not $f(k)=c\cdot k$.

Comment: @Ethan. As Jacob Schlather has said there are many possibilities depending on $g(x)$.
Supposing $g(1)\neq g(2)$, if you take $f(x)$ as:
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
g(2)-A & \textrm{if $x=1$}\\
A-g(1) & \textrm{if $x=2$}\\
0 & \textrm{if $x>2$}
\end{array} \right.$$
your conditions will be satisfied.